# If two numbers have the same average score, the number with lower id will be printed first

Tags: ruby

**If two numbers have the same average score, the number with lower id will be printed first**

```
Input
========
4
1000 8
2000 8
2000 10
1000 9

Output
=========
2000
1000
```

Could someone help me with this; tried Enumerable#chunk and its not helping.

Comment: Could you please elaborate. Do you only want one entry for the same number?

Comment: The first line on the input STDIN contains an Integer (N), that tells us how many more lines in the input. Each of the subsequent N lines contains two integers which are a number and a value respectively separated by a space.

Comment: you can pick the first integer in each line and add to a Set which will have only unique values when the process finishes, if that is what you want. You can check the documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)

Comment: @SajeeshKrishnan could you please elaborate what do you mean by score and id for the given number in input, edit your question with problem statement properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = %w|4
1000 8
2000 8
2000 10
1000 9|

count, *values = input
values.take(2 * count)  # to make use of count
      .each_slice(2)    # id, score
      .group_by(&:pop)  # by same average score
      .values           # ids
      .select { |e| e.count > 1 } # not singles
      .map { |e| e.flatten.sort_by { |e| -e.to_i } } # sort

#⇒ ["2000", "1000"]
```